# Lack of syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, and goto in VS Code for Jupyter Notebooks via remote SSH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using VS Code to edite Jupyter notebook files that are stored on a remote server (Linux, with miniconda python 3.11.6), accessed via SSH. I've encountered an issue where the syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, hover, and goto features have ceased to function on these files (although the cells still execute). These features all function properly with normal .py files on the remote server, as well as both .py *and* .ipynb files on the local machine. In other words:

|  | Local | Remote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .py | ✅ | ✅ |
| .ipynb | ✅ | ❌ |

To address this, I've tried resetting all settings and performing a clean reinstallation of my development environment. However, the problem persists. I have only the Python and Jupyter extensions installed, I haven't modified any settings, and everything is the default, with the latest versions. What could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: [Has your remote machine installation expanded?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions)

Comment: No, nothing changed on the remote or local. I have tried every solution suggested for various stack overflow questions,  including a clean install of vscode, deleting all vscode settings,  deleting vscode server, clean installing conda, and recreating conda environment , nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be related to compatibility between the latest versions of the Python extension, Pylance, and Jupyter in VS Code.

Solution:

Rolling back to previous versions of these extensions has resolved the problem for me:
See [VS Code GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5021)

Python extension: v2023.16.0
Pylance: v2023.9.30
Jupyter: v2023.8.1002501831

Any combinations newer than these versions didn't work for me. Here's how to roll back to these versions:

In VS Code, go to the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X).
For each of the extensions (Python, Pylance, Jupyter), click on the gear icon next to the extension and select Install Another Version....
Choose the specific versions mentioned above.
After rolling back, reload VS Code and the functionality should be restored for .ipynb files on the remote server.

Comment: I see you also commented in https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5043#issuecomment-1785109993. Out of curiosity, what if you switch to the pre-release channel of the Pylance extension, which is currently at v2023.10.53?

Comment: That dint work for me. The only thing that worked for me was: Python extension: v2023.16.0 Pylance: v2023.9.30 Jupyter: v2023.8.1002501831